# Using str1==str2 in System.out.println prints only true or false but does not print any text written along with it

Tags: java

Here is what i am talking about:

```
package finalExample;

public class FinalExample {

public static void main(String args[]) {

    final String str1 = "str";
    final String str2 = "ing";

    String str11 = "str";
    String str22 = "ing";

    System.out.println("Using equals() for non final :" + str11.equals(str22));
    System.out.println("Using == for non final :" + (str11==str22));
    System.out.println("MAGIC Using == for non final :" + str11==str22);

    System.out.println("Using equals() for final :" + str1.equals(str2));
    System.out.println("Using == for final :" + (str1==str2));
    System.out.println("MAGIC Using == for final :" + str1==str2);
}
```

}

Output is:

```
Using equals() for non final :false
Using == for non final :false
false
Using equals() for final :false
Using == for final :false
false
```

Both MAGIC Statements are not printed. Why is it so?

Comment: Actually, I deleted my answer. Based on the "tricky" nature of the question and the name of the class, this sounds suspiciously like a homework question...

Comment: @yshavit Yeah, these are difficult to decide on. :-/

Comment: @yshavit no it is not a homework question bro. I came across this all of a sudden while working, and i wanted to ask the reason so i wrote this example class and posted here.

Comment: Alright, then cool and sorry to be suspicious. We get that a lot on SO, unfortunately. :(

Comment: @Claudiu not exactly ! I know why are final and non final acting that way, but i wanted to know why is the MAGIC statement not printing. Still thanks for the link. :)

Comment: [Operator Precedence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `+` operator binds at a higher precedence than the `==` operator, so your expression is:

```
"MAGIC Using == for final :" + str1==str2
("MAGIC Using == for final :" + str1)==str2
(a new String object created for the comparison can't)==str2
false
```

Answer (score 3):

You are evaluating

```
"MAGIC Using == for non final :" + str11
```

which is a string, and then comparing with str2

Answer (score 2):

I think it did print. the result is false; so it prints "false"
you can think it as: 
`res = "MAGIC Using == for final :" + str1 ;
println(res == str2)`
so it prints false.